# mysql_query row values iteration problem

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a problem iterating through an sql query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// this returns 3 rows 

foreach ($row as $values) 
{ 
//fputcsv($a_csv, $values;
echo $values;
}
```

}

The script iterates fine but it appears to be going through each row twice.  So what I receive in output is the following:

value1value1value2value2value3value3

I'm not sure why this is - could anyone explain please?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches both the named & the numerical keys. Use either `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions");

//return an associative array
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// this returns 3 rows 
$values = "{$row["name_of_column1"]}, {$row["name_of_column2"]}, {$row["name_of_column3"]}";
//fputcsv($a_csv, $values;
//print the whole row array
 print_r($row);
//echo value in format value1, value2, value3
 echo $values;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `$row` like this `$row[0]` And $row shouldn't be in a foreach() itself unless it too is some kind of array you need to iterate through.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];
    // ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be in a `foreach`? There are perfectly valid reasons to do so.

Comment: 'Obiously'? It he wants a file like http://pastebin.com/PAViVJAz, a foreach would be a very valid way to do it.